What might cause this Fulltext query to be executed thousands of times. Re-enabling a Fulltext Index perhaps?
We had a complaint from a client today about the responsiveness of our application. When we looked into the Azure Query Performance Insight and the Performance Overview we noticed three queries being executed tens of thousands of times during a period of a few hours today.
Looking at the query text, each query looked like:
(@p1 int)
  select top 250
         column fulltextkey as k,
         column fulltextall
    from [dbo].[<one of our schema bound views here>]
         WITH (NOEXPAND, READCOMMITTEDLOCK)
   where column fulltextkey > @p1
order by column fulltextkey
  OPTION(MAXDOP 1)

We know that this is not a statement executed in any of our own Stored Procedures and the likes. What we DO know is that every night during downtime we check for fragmentation of tables and indexes and we rebuild those that we deem in need of a rebuild. At that stage a fulltext index may become disabled and we then re-enable it with a statement like
alter fulltext index on [dbo].<one of our schema bound views here> ENABLE

My first question: is it possible that this triggers the execution of that statement we're seeing, tens of thousands of time until, I don't know.... the fulltext index has been fully crawled or something?
and....
My second question: is there a way to reduce the strain on the database if that is the case?

Certainly looks like it might be a crawler query. If fulltextkey is indexed (along with fulltextall as an INCLUDE) then performance shouldn't really suffer much. Perhaps your index rebuilds are too aggressive: they aren't needed anywhere near as much if you have SSDs, you can let it fragment more.

Okay... These are Azure SQL databases so I actually don't know what they are really physically stored on. Can you clarify a little bit what you mean by "fulltextkey" and "fulltextall"?

I'm just referring to the column in your query where column fulltextkey > @p1 or whatever that was actually supposed to be before you obfuscated it. Please show the definition of the table along with all indexes and FTS index.

The only thing I obfuscated is the name of the schema bound view. The rest of the query is exactly as reported to us by Query Performance Insight apart from a little indentation to make it easier to read. The View is a join over 4 tables with a Unique Clustered Key over an INT and 3 more columns, another INT, a VARCHAR(20) and a VARCHAR(MAX). Only that latter VARCHAR(MAX) column is included in the fulltext index.

So the text where column fulltextkey > @p1 is actually in the query? Weird, it's not even valid SQL. Definitely something internal then. I suggest you get the mods to migrate this to [dba.se] where there are better subject experts.

Thanks for the suggestion..... would you believe it I've been on SO for a few years now but I've never had the need to ask for migrating a query.... how do I do that?

Thanks @Charlieface I have flagged question as per your suggestion
